$k$-algebra homomorphism between coordinate rings
This is in Dummit&Foote's Abstact Algebra about commutative rings and algebraic geometry.

Suppose that $\phi$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism from the coordinate ring $k[W] = k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]/\mathcal{I}(W)$ to $k[V] = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathcal{I}(V)$. Let $F_i$ be a representative of the image of $\overline{x}_i \in k[W]$, that is, $\phi(\overline{x}_i\ \operatorname{mod}(\mathcal{I}(W))) = F_i\ \operatorname{mod}(\mathcal{I}(V))$. Then we have that $\varphi = (F_1,\ldots,F_n)$ defines a polynomial from $\mathbb{A}^n$ to $\mathbb{A}^m$, and in fact, $\varphi$ is a morphism from $V$ to $W$. To see this it suffices to check that $\varphi$ maps a point of $V$ to a point of $W$ since by definition $\varphi$ is already defined by polynomials. If $g \in \mathcal{I}(W) \subset k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ then in $k[W]$ we have
$$
> g(x_1 + \mathcal{I}(W),\ldots,x_m + \mathcal{I}(W)) = g(x_1,\ldots,x_m)+\mathcal{I}(W) = \mathcal{I}(W) = 0 \in k[W],
> $$

What does the notation $g(x_1 + \mathcal{I}(W),\ldots,x_m + \mathcal{I}(W))$ mean? $g$ is a polynomial in $k[x_1,\cdots,x_m]$ vanishing on $W$, $x_i+\mathcal{I}(W)$ is an element in $k[W] = k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]/\mathcal{I}(W)$.

Generally if you have a ring homomorphism $\iota:k\to k'$ you can, for any polynomial
$$g=\sum_\alpha a_\alpha x^\alpha\in k[x_1,\dots,x_m]$$
define another polynomial
$$\iota(g)=\sum_\alpha \iota(a_\alpha)x^\alpha\in k'[x_1,\dots,x_m].$$
So what you do is take you polynomial over one field and simply map its coefficients to the other field.
Now in your case you have a canonical choice of homomorphism, namely the injection
\begin{align*}
\iota:k&\hookrightarrow k[W],\\
a&\mapsto a+\mathcal{I}(W).
\end{align*}
As this map is very canonical, and we often identify $k$ as a subset of $k[W]$ under this map (but without writing it explicitly) we also omit it in this case. But if you follow the construction above this is exactly what you get.

Thanks for your answering. But as you stated, $k'=k[W]$ and $\iota(g)\in k[W][x_1,\cdots,x_m]=(k[x_1,\cdots,x_m]/\mathcal{I}(W))[x_1,\cdots,x_m]$, which make me confused about this notation containing two polynomial rings.

@QuayChern If you want to make it more explicit then what the proof says is that $$\iota(g)(x_1+\mathcal{I}(W),\dots,x_m+\mathcal{I}(W))=g(x_1,\dots,x_m)+\mathcal{I}(W).$$ Does this make it clearer?

Oh, I get it. Denote by $R=k[W]$ the coordinate ring then $x_i+\mathcal{I}(W)$ are elements in $R$, so $\iota(g)\in k[W][y_1,\cdots,y_m]=(k[x_1,\cdots,x_m]/\mathcal{I}(W))[y_1,\cdots,y_m]=R[y_1,\cdots,y_m]$, and $\iota(g)(x_1+\mathcal{I}(W),\cdots,x_m+\mathcal{I}(W))$ is just evaluating $\iota(g)(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$ at $(x_1+\mathcal{I}(W),\cdots,x_m+\mathcal{I}(W))$. Thanks for your reply.
